# change image fo UIImageview

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uitableview

In cellForRowAtIndexPath method add this code

```
cell.imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
cell.imageView.tag = indexPath.row;

UITapGestureRecognizer *tapped = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(myFunction:)];
tapped.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
[cell.imageView addGestureRecognizer:tapped];   
[tapped release];
```

And then to check which imageView was clicked, check the flag in selector method

```
-(void)myFunction :(id) sender
{
UITapGestureRecognizer *gesture = (UITapGestureRecognizer *) sender;
NSLog(@"Tag = %d", gesture.view.tag);
}.
```

Now I would like to set the tapped image view with other image.

Comment: `[(UIImageView *)gesture.view setImage:yourImage]`?

Comment: cell.itemIcon.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
cell.itemIcon.tag=indexPath.row;  and itemIcon hold by default image. but when I tap how can i change the cell.itemIcon image in.-(void)myFunction :(id) sender
{
UITapGestureRecognizer *gesture = (UITapGestureRecognizer *) sender;
NSLog(@"Tag = %d", gesture.view.tag);
}.